# Android Development : Getting data from the web

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in Android development and I am trying to make an app that will simply display the posts on the following website http://www.montgomeryschoolsmd.org/schools/lakelandsparkms/. I need to know how can I display the data from the web into my android app. An example would be appreciated.

Comment: You know the http response has the html code of the page requested...

Comment: You mean simply loading this URL or in your android app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to display posts into an Android application will be to use JSON data on the web, and read it into a Master Detail Android application.

On the website side, getting the data to display in JSON seems to be the most difficult part of your problem. It would be easy if it was a Wordpress site, as there are plugins that will do this for you.

On the application side, getting the data and parsing it into a master detail flow is a fairly trivial task.

Something like this tutorial may help: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/ or this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TulTqQM0Cc

Answer (score 2):

You can make a Json request and show data with android views.  Or you can download the full or partial page and show it directly in a webview.

Answer (score 2):

Use Jsoup if you're trying to scrape the webpage for data and display it in a UI.