# Pulling data from the web via an android web app

Tags: android-studio

I'm building an app in Android Studio, and I'd like to know how I can get the app to return information from an online database such as http://www.worldcat.org/?  I seldom have an idea about the best way to do this part. Your help is much appreciated.

***NOTE: I am all for constructive criticism but please leave any/all useless or sarcastic commentary to yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Development : Getting data from the web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396814/android-development-getting-data-from-the-web)

Comment: I wonder which kind of information do you want to return and which other databases do you consider? Did you try and fetch the website content directly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to return basic information about any given book such as the author, publisher etc.  I'm even open to pulling from other online book databases if it can provide the number of pages for the book.  Thanks.